# How do I know if `collapse_key` is working on FCM/GCM?

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using a collapse key in my payload to FCM
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#collapsible_and_non-collapsible_messages

Is there somewhere on google services where I can verify these are configured correctly?

I don't see any indication in the docs on how to tell if it is configured right.  I know I can turn off a device and seeing what happens when you stack them up.  It seems straight forward since it is just a key value pair, but I would love to verify implementation before launching.

The notifications I am sending still come through so that is a good sign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look at them in the GCM/FCM console and it will tell you there.  You just need the unique id of one of your pushes that is returned on a successful request.